# How to disable production mode in Angular2?

Tags: angular, debugging

I use the function `isDevMode()` to enable/disable logs, but I would like to debug in production with the logs, after calling `enableProdMode()`

In AngularJS there was a method callable from the console called `reloadWithDebugInfo()` to reload the app in dev mode.

Is there something similar in Angular2?

Comment: Just for the future: Create your own service that provides a property LogLevel and check this in all places where you like to use log messages.

Comment: @Oliver That's what I do, but I need to check and change what level is logging after the website is on production

Comment: Then put a switch somewhere on a settings page where you can change the current LogLevel.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same like this  :

Create a file (ts) with the following code

```
  export const environment = {
      production: false
    };
```

Then In `main.ts` file import the class and then

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

Comment: I need to debug production code where I cannot edit the code, but only work from website console.